# My module freezes magento admin menu

Tags: php, xml, magento, content-management-system

So I have created my own magento extension.

When i log in and navigate to my module admin-tab, it works as its supposed to with the controller and phtml file. But once i enter my admin tab, the entire admin navigation menu seems to freeze/be stuck

I'm talking about the menu with "Dashboard, Sales, Catalog, Mobile etc etc". So once i entered my own module page through that menu, the menu gets stuck. If anybody got any clue how to solve this, or where this problem is occuring, it would be a great help.

my controller

```
class Lars_XFeed_Adminhtml_TestController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
public function indexAction()
{
   $this->loadLayout();
   $this->renderLayout();
}
```

my config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Lars_XFeed>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Lars_XFeed>
  </modules>
  <global>
        <helpers>
            <xfeed>
                <class>Lars_XFeed_Helper</class>
            </xfeed>
        </helpers>
      </global>
      <blocks>
        <xfeed>
          <class>Lars_XFeed_Block</class>
        </xfeed>
      </blocks>
  <admin>
    <routers>
        <lars_xfeed>
                        <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Lars_XFeed</module>
                                <frontName>xfeed</frontName>
            </args>
        </lars_xfeed>
    </routers>
  </admin>
  <adminhtml>
    <layout>
      <updates>
                  <xfeed>
                      <file>xfeed.xml</file>
                  </xfeed>
          </updates>
      </layout>
  </adminhtml>

</config>
```

my block:

```
class Lars_XFeed_Block_Adminhtml_Xfeedbackend extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template{
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setTemplate('xfeed/test.phtml')
    $this->setFormAction(Mage::getUrl('*/*/new'));
    $this->setFormAction(Mage::getUrl('*/*/remove'));
}       
}
```

my adminhtml.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <lars_xfeed>
            <title>Lars</title>
            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
            <children>
                <test>
                    <title>Lars Settings</title>
                    <action>lars_xfeed/adminhtml_test</action>
                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                </test>
            </children>
        </lars_xfeed>
    </menu>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everthing</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <lars_xfeed>
                        <title>Lars Settings</title>
                        <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    </lars_xfeed>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
        <layout>
      <updates>
                  <xfeed>
                      <file>xfeed.xml</file>
                  </xfeed>
          </updates>
      </layout>
</config>
```

Comment: Flush caches and then re-login

Comment: thx but doesnt solve my problem